# Deployed NFT contract with wrong Alchemy key

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, nft

Accidentally deployed an NFT contract with an Alchemy key from app set to Goerli Network on Ethereum Mainnet.

[image]

I had it set up for testing ... but forgot to change it when I deployed. How will this impact the contract?

From `hardhat.config.js`

```
    mainnet: {
      chainId: 1,
      url: `https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_GOERLI_KEY}`,
      accounts: [`0x${ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY}`],
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 8000000000
    },
```

Can the network be changed on alchemy.com dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

No, the contract was deployed on Goerli and there is nothing you can do about it. The contract is not "affected" in any way, it just lives in a different network.

Comment: No ... the contract was deployed on mainnet ... It just had that alchemy key ... I can find it on etherscan. And was able to mint an nft using my Metamask with Mainnet network selected. Just to be safe ... I think I'll redeploy with the correct key ... there's not activity on it anyway ... just my test.